# Using jade to create an unordered list tree

Tags: node.js, express, tree, html-lists, pug

I have an object called `boundedArea` which contains an array of `boundedArea` objects in a field `children` and I would like to create a tree of unordered lists.

I have the following code:

```
- for (var index = 0; index < rootAreas.length; index++) {
  - var boundedArea = rootAreas[index];
  div(class='panel panel-default')
    div.panel-heading
      | #{boundedArea.NAME}
    div.panel-body
      - printChildren(boundedArea, 0); 
- }
- 
- function printChildren(boundedArea, depth) {
  - var children = boundedArea.children;
  - if (children == null || children.length == 0) {
    - return;
  - } 
  ul  
  - for (var index = 0; index < children.length; index++) {
    - var child = children[index];
    li #{child.NAME}
    - console.log("Printing %s child of %s", child.NAME, boundedArea.NAME);
    - printChildren(child, depth + 1); 
  - } 
- }
```

Now obviously this sort of works in that it prints out all the values. However because the `ul` and `li` tags are a fixed indentation in they do not nest and just ended up printing sequentially.

Is there any way to dynamically set the level of indent or to force these to nest. Or should I be using a completely different model of nesting altogether.

I tried cretaing a javascript variable indent filled with two spaces for each depth level and then tried to use `#{indent}` but that just ended up creating tags with spaces in which was not what I wanted. Though that implies that something around this idea could work as it must be resolved at some level before but the it is picked up as a token of some kind.

Comment: What is your plan for making an array to tree? When you decide the form of tree , 'balanced binary tree' for example, levels of nodes could be calculated in natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a mixin instead of a function. Mixins respect/remember the level of indentation (not really sure why functions don't).

```
mixin printChildren(boundedArea, depth)
  - var children = boundedArea.children;
  - if (children == null || children.length == 0)
    - return;
  ul  
    - for (var index = 0; index < children.length; index++)
      - var child = children[index];
      li #{child.NAME}
        +printChildren(child, depth + 1)

- for (var index = 0; index < rootAreas.length; index++)
  - var boundedArea = rootAreas[index];
  div(class='panel panel-default')
    div.panel-heading
      | #{boundedArea.NAME}
    div.panel-body
      +printChildren(boundedArea, 0)
```

I tweaked your code a bit. Mixins are invoked using a `+` instead of a `-` and they need to be defined before they are used.

I tested it with this sample data:

```
{
  rootAreas: [
    {
      NAME: 'area1',
      children: [
        { NAME: 'child1' },
        { NAME: 'child2' },
        { 
          children: [
            { NAME: 'child3' },
            { NAME: 'child4' },
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      NAME: 'area2',
      children: [
        { NAME: 'child5' },
        { NAME: 'child6' },
        { NAME: 'child7' },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the template yielded this HTML code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">area1</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul> 
      <li>child1</li>
      <li>child2</li>
      <li>
        <ul> 
          <li>child3</li>
          <li>child4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">area2</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul> 
      <li>child5</li>
      <li>child6</li>
      <li>child7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I understood you correctly, this is what you're looking for.

Comment: just a quick note, as i ran into syntax errors using this: The call had to be `+printChidlren(group, depth)` for me (no space between `+` und `printChildren` and no semicolon at the end